# Deleting local branch in VS2019 after successful pull request

Tags: git, azure-devops

Following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branches?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio

I created a feature branch off of Master, made a change, committed that to the server, reviewed the pull request, and in completing it, dev ops deleted the feature branch from the server.

However locally the feature branch still remains, so is this the expected behaviour? As devs are we meant to delete the local branch ourselves? Just wondering what is the flow/process for local branches after merged with master?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected behavior. It is how git works.

You can check for example [this article](http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/Clean-up-your-local-branches-after-merge-and-delete-in-GitHub.html) by @Fizer Khan for a deeper explanation.